# Code compiles, yet DbContext.SaveChanges() ultimately tries to cast [...]Generic.List`1[x]' to type 'x'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3.1

I have just completed re-factoring some code, and I now have this error when saving the `DbContext` following some calculation code that shouldn't have been affected by the changes I've just made.

The error is:

> {"Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[_3T.NewDomain.Quote.Pricing.PriceLineItem]'
>   to type '_3T.NewDomain.Quote.Pricing.PriceLineItem'."}

It's triggered when calling: `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

I will embark upon what I anticipate to be a fairly lengthy debugging process.  But, I'm completely perplexed as to how the code can compile okay.  Yet the `DbContext` is trying to assign a list to a single instance variable.

Is there any gotcha people have come across that can lead to something like this?
What have I overlooked?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ric.  I couldn't think what code would be pertinent to show.  Really I was after a 'given the evidence so far, start looking here'.  I've since figured it out, and now know (with hindsight) that the EF fluent config code would have been the relevant snippet to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer.  I'm posting it here in case it helps others.

Given the error was EF related, and the code compiled, I started with the assumption that it was most likely a configuration error.

To give some additional information: The `PriceLineItem` class, at the focus of the error, can be nested within itself providing a tree structure.  There are also some classes that inherit from `PriceLineItem`, such as `IssuePriceLineItem`.

Early when I started out with this new tree structure, I defined the following configuration manually in my `DbContext` class using the fluent API:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<IssuePriceLineItem>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.PriceLineItems)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentLineItemId);
```

This relic from the tinkering stage is where the error lies.  You can see that it implies a many-to-many relationship. This can be fixed by altering line 2, or 2 and 3 of this config.

Correction 1:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<IssuePriceLineItem>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.ParentLineItem)
   .WithMany() /* implies ICollection<PriceLineItem> PriceLineItems */
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentLineItemId);
```

Correction 2:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<IssuePriceLineItem>()
   .HasMany(p => p.PriceLineItems)
   .WithOptional() /* implies ParentLineItem navigation property */
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentLineItemId);
```

Either way, in this specific case, I should have had it defined as self-referencing using `PriceLineItem` and not `IssuePriceLineItem`.  If it had been self-referencing from the start, the erroneous config would have come to light earlier.  Instead of sitting dormant until my recent refactoring kicked it into play.

**In my mind the safest config definition** is to be more explicit, as below:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<PriceLineItem>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.ParentLineItem)
    .WithMany(p => p.PriceLineItems)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentLineItemId);
```

**However, the best fix** (IMO) is to remove this entry entirely. Since with the property names used, convention over configuration sufficiently takes care of this relationship definition